# LaTeX table of contents using package curve

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I'm struggling for some hours now on how to make a table of contents when using the CurVe class.
The class hasn't defined commands such as \tableofcontents, \section, etc.

Any ideas on how to associate a toc to the rubrics? and display the toc with \tableofcontents or make the command "\tableofrubrics"?

E.g., I want to make the table of contents/rubrics in this example: https://github.com/ArwensAbendstern/CV-LaTeX/tree/master/full%20CurVe%20CV%20English.

```
Professional Experience .... 1
Education................... 1
etc.
```

thank you!

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,12pt,english]{curve} % your specs, esp the language of your CV

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % special characters, etc.
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry} % adapt to your specs

\usepackage[english]{babel} % the language of your CV
\usepackage{textcomp} % Trademarks and other symbols

\usepackage{color} % e.g. for coloured links
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % clickable links in the PDF
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}  % defines link colour

%%% setup the options for the hyperref package
\hypersetup{%
 pdftex=true,%
 colorlinks=true,% 
 breaklinks=true,%
 linkcolor=darkblue,%
 menucolor=darkblue,%
 urlcolor=darkblue,%
 }

%%% if you want to include flavors:
% \flavor{corp} % corp version of the experience rubric
% \flavor{academic} % academic version of the experience rubric

%%% if you want different title styles
% \input{title.online.ltx}
% \input{title.print.ltx}

%%% if you don't need different title styles:

\title{Graduate Student} % Who are you? e. g. Assistant Professor, Chief Engineer, Senior Executive 

\subtitle{at the Peace Institute, Z\"urich, Switzerland} % a bit more info about you

% vertical space after subrubric
\setlength \subrubricspace{3ex} % CurVe default: 5pt

% special characters as bullet point symbols
 \usepackage{pifont} % only if you need them
 \prefix{\ding{43}} % pointing finger as a bullet list item symbol 

% if rubric is spread onto multiple pages, the rubric name is repeated and followed by:
\continuedname{~~(continued)} % for a CV in English


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{rubric}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\newline#1\dotfill}%
  %% \begin{rubric}
  \def\raggedright{%
    \@rightskip\@flushglue\rightskip\@rightskip\leftskip\z@skip}%
  \def\raggedleft{%
    \rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue\parfillskip\z@skip}%
  \gdef\@beforespace{0pt}%
  \gdef\@nextentry{}%
  \gdef\@previouskey{}%
  \global\let\old@newpage\newpage%
  \global\let\old@pagebreak\pagebreak%
  \global\let\old@nopagebreak\nopagebreak
  \begin{longtable}{@{}kl@{~}X@{}}
    \@rubrichead{#1}\\*[\rubricspace]
    \endfirsthead
    \@rubrichead{#1\@continuedname}\\*[\rubricspace]
    \endhead
    \noalign{\@rubricmark{#1}%
      \global\let\in@newpage\newpage%
      \global\let\in@pagebreak\pagebreak%
      \global\let\in@nopagebreak\nopagebreak%
      \gdef\newpage{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@newpage}
      \gdef\pagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@pagebreak}
      \gdef\nopagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@nopagebreak}}}{%
    %% \end{rubric}
    \@nextentry
  \end{longtable}\par\vspace\rubricafterspace
  \global\let\newpage\old@newpage%
  \global\let\pagebreak\old@pagebreak%
  \global\let\nopagebreak\old@nopagebreak}



\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

% call the rubric files in preferred order
% make sure your file names are correct

\makerubric{experience} % calls experience.ltx
\makerubric{education}  % calls education.ltx
\makerubric{skills} % calls skills.ltx
\makerubric{references} % calls references.ltx
\makerubric{publications} % calls publications.ltx

\end{document} % end of main document CV.ltx
```

[image]